# Can document.querySelector() Find an IMG Element According to a SRC FileName (instead of full URL)?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors

I am currently using `document.querySelector()` to Find an `IMG` Element on the current page,
via supplying the `SRC` Attribute's value of that `IMG` Element.

For example, I use this line:

```
var E =document.querySelector("img[src='https://images.website.com/folder1/folder2/12345.gif']");
```

As can be seen, in this example I have the **full URL** for the Image that is specified in the `SRC` Attribute,
and I give that full URL to `document.querySelector()`.

I now need to slightly improve this:

There are cases where I only know the Image's **File Name**,
and the Folders part of the URL may change, and is unknown to me.

So my question is:
Can I use `document.querySelector()` to Find an `IMG` Element on the current page,
when I only know the FileName part of the Image's URL?

In the above example, it would mean that I have "12345.gif",
but I don't know the names of folder1, folder2..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Attributes can be matched by different signs.

```
[attr] // attribute itself
[attr=value] // is value
[attr~=value] // contains a word containing value
[attr|=value] // contains a complete word value
[attr^=value] // begins with value
[attr$=value] // ends with value
[attr*=value] // contains a part of value
```

In your example check for
`[src$=12345.gif]`

Comment: Thank you very much Markus, it works terrific. BTW, when going to document.querySelector()'s Reference ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector ) I did not see that list of Suffixes that you show.. Is it in another place there? or where could I have found it when looking myself?

Comment: You can read the details as in [attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_attribute_selectors.asp).